# Update on account is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the below 2 code samples one is working and one is not. Can you please help correct the 2nd example that is not working.

### Example 1: working

```
public class Accountcustom{
    public String accountID;
    public Account acc {get;set;}

    public Accountcustom(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        accountID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        acc = [select id, name, phone FROM Account WHERE id =: accountID]; 
    }

    public void Save(){           
        update acc;
    }

}
```

### Example 2 : Not Working

```
public class Accountcustom{

    public String accountID;
    public Account acc {get;set;}

    public Accountcustom(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        accountID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    }

    public void Save(){           
        acc = [select id, name, phone FROM Account WHERE id =: accountID]; 
        update acc;
    }
}
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Accountcustom">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
        <apex:commandbutton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
        <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
        <apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!Delete}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="Account Name"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="Phone"/><apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first Example, you fetch the `account` from the Database at the time of page load and show it to the User. So whenever the user changes the `Name` and `Phone` in VF page it is stored in the `acc` variable. When you call `save` method, the `acc` variable is updated in the database.

But in the second example, you are not fetching the `account` at the time of page load. So `acc` will hold a non initialized blank account. In your `save` method, you fetch the `accoun`t from database and assign to `acc` variable and update the same. This doesn't reflect the `account` modified in the VF page by the User. That's why you are not seeing the changed values in Database.

In constructor initialize the `acc` variable

```
acc = new Account();
```

In save method, instead of query

```
acc.id = accountId;
Update acc;
```

You need to change the Account.Phone in VF page to acc.Phone

```
<apex:outputText value="Account Name"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/>
<apex:outputText value="Phone"/><apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
```

to

```
<apex:outputText value="Account Name"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/>
<apex:outputText value="Phone"/><apex:inputField value="{!acc.Phone}"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what can I write after the query to reflect the changes in account retrieved before updating it.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain the changes need to be done.

Comment: In this case - acc.id = accountId; How is the account name updating to 'acc' ?

Comment: In VF page you specify acc.Name and acc.Phone to instruct salesforce to store those fields in acc variable. In Save method, when you specify acc.id = accountid and update acc, you are instructing salesforce to update the Name and Phone values in acc variable to the record with the id specified in accountid.

Answer (score 2):

In first Example you fetch record when your constructor invoke means when your page loaded, than you updates values for this record than update.  and in second example you fetch database record when click on save button and just update, means by clicking save button you fetch record and update same without any changes. because both statements execute when you press save button.

Comment: cant understand your explanation :(