# Newbie Question: Saving Visualforce Input to object

Tags: visualforce

Similar to this question: [Update on account is not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84017/update-on-account-is-not-working)

I am trying to change the value of a record's field by whatever the user inputs on a visualforce page.  The visualforce page is written in HTML.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="RepricingController" sidebar="false">

<script>
function checkForNAeBay(id, partslink, store) {
    var a = "http://google.com";
    if (id === "NA" || id === null || id === "") {
        a = "http://stores.ebay.com/" + store + "?_dmd=2&_nkw=" + partslink;
    } else {
        a = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/" + id;
    }
    return a;
}

function getURL(){
    return "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="updateAll" action="{!updateAll}"/>
</apex:form>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Repricing Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" align="">
            <apex:repeat value="{!repricing_objects}" var="repricing" id="main_repeat">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="dropdown" style="display:{!If(repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_ID_Depot__c != null,'','none')}">
                            <p class="clickablefont">
                                {!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_Price_Depot__c}
                            </p>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <p>Shipping: {!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_Shipping_Depot__c}</p>
                                <a href="javascript:window.open(checkForNAeBay('{!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_ID_Depot__c}', '{!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Linked_Product__r[$Setup.PDI_Repricing__Repricing_Settings__c.PDI_Repricing__Partslink_Field__c]}', '{!$Setup.PDI_Repricing__Repricing_Settings__c.PDI_Repricing__HeadlightsDepot_Store_Label__c}'));">
                                View Product
                                </a>
                                <a href="javascript:window.open(getURL());" target="_blank">TEST</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown" style="display:{!If(repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_ID_Depot__c == null,'','none')}">
                            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mono-general-1/512/alert-icon.png" width="20" height="20" class="clickable"/>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <p>No Item ID found!</p>
                            
                                <input value="{!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_ID_Depot__c}"/>
                            
                                <button type="button" onclick="updateAll()">
                                    Update
                                </button>
                            
                                <a href="javascript:window.open(checkForNAeBay('{!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_ID_Depot__c}', '{!repricing.PDI_Repricing__Linked_Product__r[$Setup.PDI_Repricing__Repricing_Settings__c.PDI_Repricing__Partslink_Field__c]}', '{!$Setup.PDI_Repricing__Repricing_Settings__c.PDI_Repricing__HeadlightsDepot_Store_Label__c}'));">
                                Find ID
                                </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public List<PDI_Repricing__Repricing_Info__c> repricing_objects {get;set;}



public RepricingController(){
    this.repricing_objects = get_repricing_info();
}

public PageReference updateAll() {
    System.debug('UPDATING: ');
    for (PDI_Repricing__Repricing_Info__c o : repricing_objects){
        System.debug(o.PDI_Repricing__Our_eBay_ID_Depot__c);
    }
    update repricing_objects;
    return null;
}
```

After a value is placed in the input box and the 'update' button is clicked, the page refreshes and the value of the field in Pricing Info does not change.  I also have page messages on the page and no errors appear in the console.

I'm only showing relevant code, so if you need more code please ask.

So any ideas why my record is not being updated?  Nothing is being updated, in fact.

EDIT:

Debug:

> 11:57:17:037 USER_DEBUG [101]|DEBUG|UPDATING:
>
> 11:57:17:039 USER_DEBUG [103]|DEBUG|370924410604 //note this was already here, not put in by the user
>
> 11:57:17:040 USER_DEBUG [103]|DEBUG|null
>
> 11:57:17:041 USER_DEBUG [103]|DEBUG|null
>
> 11:57:17:042 USER_DEBUG [103]|DEBUG|null
>
> 11:57:17:043 USER_DEBUG [103]|DEBUG|null
>
> 11:57:17:044 USER_DEBUG [103]|DEBUG|null

Comment: is that entire page given? what's inside JS method updateAll()? Does that really call controller method?

Comment: Edited.  The entire page is not given (only like 5% of it is), added the JS method, sorry. The updateAll() in the controller runs properly, and it does print the debug information, but the objects are not updated (the value from the input box is never seen on the debug console)

Comment: Change your HTML `<button>` to `<apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!updateAll}" />`

Comment: @DougB the button is wrapped in html and is outside of any apex forms or page blocks, and would require me to wrap it in an apex form, does that matter?

Comment: Yes, the button should be in the <apex:form /> tag.

Comment: @DougB Okay, I updated it but that change seemed to not be related to my problem, thanks though.

Comment: Is your method running?  Do the debug logs output the Ids?  I'm thinking this may have something to do with the `<input value="{!pricing.Our_ID__c}"/>` not also being within the `<apex:form>` tag.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing everything involved (since what's "relevant" is relative), but the page doesn't actually pass the object to the controller. It can pass an Id that allows you to know which object is being referenced, but you need to query the object the page references separately before you can update it. If you're not querying the object, I'd guess you're updating a newly created "blank" pricing object, and the only value you're giving it is the Our_Id__c, which isn't enough for it to update itself (it needs the actual object Id).

Comment: @KB145 Simplification must not be proper to help you guys, sorry about that.  I've copied and edited in my raw, unsimplified code (still not all of it because I don't agree with code dumping). Doug, The method is running and the debug is in the edit.

Comment: Did you try Devendra's solution? It does appear the debug shows null because the original value was null, and it's simply not being set/receiving the input value. If you use inputText (which I'm assuming is similar to your use of input) instead of inputField, you need to write additional code to access the value from the controller and bind it. If you use inputField, it binds to the object's field once the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input value="{!pricing.Our_ID__c}"/>
```

you can try,

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pricing.Our_ID__c}"/>
```

And  should be inside the form tag.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This worked (I had to wrap the whole HTML in a form)! Thank you!